# 1 Server Multi cPanel, how the apache work?

Tags: cpanel, dedicated-server

i want to ask something about dedicated server.

i have dedicated server and a cPanel website with heavy load, when i check the server load, all parameter didn't go up to 60% usage. but the apache work is high.

so i wonder if i can do this.

i buy dedicated server(DS) and install 2 cPanel on same DS. i know that cPanel need an IP to bind the license so i add 1 additional IP to my DS.

what i am trying to archieve here is to split workload in same website, and to split the traffic i use loadbalancer from CF.

so i have abc.com with 2 different IPs and use LoadBalancer to split the load.

here is why i need to do this

1. Server load relative low (under 80%)
2. Apache load relative high 3-10 req/s

Comment: If you think Apache is being limited in some way, just find that limit and change it - it's your server. Installing two copies of the same software on the server is extremely unlikely to be an efficient configuration.

Comment: @IMSoP will there any problem if i unlimit the apache worker setting?

Comment: There'll be a lot less problem than trying to install it twice on the server! Why don't you test it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your problem definition
What do you mean by Apache work?

if you want have more threads and processes of Apache httpd on the same server, you dont need to install two Cpanel instances, you could tune your Apache httpd worker configuration for a better performance and resource utilization.

you can even use litespeed or nginx web servers on cpanel.

Comment: i try to split apache work load, so i wonder if i can install 2 cpanel on same machine dan having load balancer to split work between the cpanel